# Invoking child class methods without classloading parent class?

Tags: java, parent-child, classloader

Is it possible to compile java class child of parent class, that
invoking method of child class does't requre load of parent class.

May be compile or run with some advanced option.

For example
I have 3 classes

```
public class Parent {
    public void baseMethod(){
        System.out.println("Parent.baseMethod invoked");
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent{
     public void childMethod(){
         System.out.println("Child.childMethod invoked");
    }

}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Child().childMethod();
    }
}
```

I compile them, and delete Parent.class.

I want to run

```
java Main
```

without exeption

Comment: If you want to delete the parent class, then you don't need its methods and properties. If you don't need its methods and properties, why do you want to extend it?

Comment: besides the obvious need to load the parent class [resulting in NoClassDefFoundError], the invisible constructor of the Child does contain a call to the super constructor. So you cannot compile neither you can run time with the Parent class.

Comment: Jigar Joshi, i trying to find possible bug in my bussness app. Cannot find requed parent class in classpath, but all works

Comment: the parent class may be loaded through a special classloader. For that case, it doesn't have to be stored relative to any classpath entry. Try to find uses of `Classloader` or `URLClassloader` in your application!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Way. Java will always load the superclasses. The superclass is *required* to create the actual instance.

Creating a new `Child` will do an implicit call to `Parent()` and that's when you need the `Parent` class **loaded**.

---

PS - doesn't even work if you just want to call a static method on the subclass, like that:

```
public class Parent {}
public class Child {public static void hello(){System.out.println("hello");}}
public class Caller{public static void main(String[] args){Child.hello();}}
```

deleting `Parent.class` will throw a `NoClassDefFoundError` even though no instance of `Child` was ever created.

Answer (score 3):

**No**

It will load Parent class , That is why  inheritance is there.

When `extends Parent` comes it will look for `Parent` class and load it to make relationship

**See Also**

- [12.2.1    The Loading Process](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/execution.doc.html)

Comment: +1 for the link. I searched myself and didn't come up with anything similar. I'm surprised the tutorial doesn't go into depth like that.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work that way.

When a class is loaded, first all of it's super classes are loaded. And if they can't be found, the class can't be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance means: Child **IS** Parent, so you cannot.

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the super classes or a class to load a class.

The only options you have if this is undesirable is to

- Make the Child no longer a sub-class of the Parent, either in code or at runtime with byte code manipulation.
- Replace the Parent with another version which does what you want, or doesn't do what you don't want (again either in code or at runtime)